# Avoiding Excel range difragmantation with Areas So append such form of filtered range at one PDF result

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, append, pdf-generation

I want create report from a filtered Table of Worksheet in One pdf file.

This have two approach:

**(1)**

1- Using `Print Area`, that works **correctly** in this episode of exporting pdf.

2- Using given Range to `.ExportAsFixedFormat` with `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` Range which that generating **wrong** result with fragmented `Areas` section in pdf.

*In this episode of this question, sub question is why above range had fragmented and how can correct this?*

**How can I do that with avoid of Range fragmentation  by `Areas`?**

**(2) appending result to previous pdf**

This report needs several filtered result type of change programmatically one specific column criteria in above Table.

Of course, the Table has some filtered rows or columns.

**Thus, How can I append such filtered form of Table in new section page at the end of the pdf report file?** (without save and merge several pdf s; so appending quietly in memory (or in one file) and publish resulted pdf.)

I tried code below but...

```
Sub PDFExport()

Dim Rng As Range

ActiveSheet.Unprotect

Set Rng = Range("tblInsRep[#All]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4:H" & _
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tblInsRep").ListRows.Count + 4).Address

Rng.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    fileName:=ThisWorkbook.path & "rep.pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True


ActiveSheet.Protect AllowFiltering:=True

End Sub
```

Produced Non-coherent pdf file as Fragmented with filtered rows and columns by `Areas`, each `Area` sectioned in new page! **(Episode ONE of sub question)**

How ever I followed `CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")` solutions for appending an Excel range at end of source pdf but cant reach summed up result, contains two above issues solution integrated.**Episode TWO of sub question)**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best will be to copy the data you are wanting to get onto the PDF to "Helper" sheet and then save that sheet as PDF.

What will help to get each section of copied info to another sheet is to insert page breaks after each set of data is copied.

See code below:

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub PDFExport()

        Dim CopyRng As Range
        Dim HelpSheetLastRow As Long
        Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
        Dim HelperSheet As Worksheet

        Set DataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetNameHere")

        Set HelperSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add

        DataSheet.Unprotect

        'Set some range to the cells you want to copy
        '
        '

            'If there is a named range tblInsRep in your sheet
            Dim tblInsRepRowNum As Long
            'Provided that there is a named range in the sheet with name tblInsRep
            tblInsRepRowNum = DataSheet.Range("tblInsRep").Rows.Count

            Set CopyRng = DataSheet.Range(DataSheet.Cells(4, "A"), _
                                          DataSheet.Cells(4 + tblInsRepRowNum, "H"))

        With HelperSheet
            '  +2 to have a line betwen the data entries
            HelpSheetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 2

            .Range(.Cells(HelpSheetLastRow, 1), _
                   .Cells(1 + CopyRng.Rows.Count, 1 + CopyRng.Columns.Count)) = CopyRng.Value
        End With


        'Set some range to the cells you want to copy

            Set CopyRng = DataSheet.Range(DataSheet.Cells(4, "A"), _
                                      DataSheet.Cells(4 + tblInsRepRowNum, "H"))

        '
        '
        '

        With HelperSheet
            '  +2 to have a line betwen the data entries
            HelpSheetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 2

            'Inserting a page break will ensure the next copied range is start on the next page
            .HPageBreaks.Add .Cells(HelpSheetLastRow, 1)

            .Range(.Cells(HelpSheetLastRow, 1), _
                   .Cells(HelpSheetLastRow + CopyRng.Rows.Count, 1 + CopyRng.Columns.Count)) = CopyRng.Value
        End With


        'Set some range to the cells you want to copy

            Set CopyRng = DataSheet.Range(DataSheet.Cells(4, "A"), _
                                      DataSheet.Cells(4 + tblInsRepRowNum, "H"))

        '
        '
        '

        With HelperSheet
            '  +2 to have a line betwen the data entries
            HelpSheetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 2

            'Inserting a page break will ensure the next copied range is start on the next page
            .HPageBreaks.Add .Cells(HelpSheetLastRow, 1)

            .Range(.Cells(HelpSheetLastRow, 1), _
                   .Cells(HelpSheetLastRow + CopyRng.Rows.Count, 1 + CopyRng.Columns.Count)) = CopyRng.Value
        End With



        'ActiveSheet saves the PDF without splitting the ranges.
        HelperSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                        Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\rep.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                                        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                                        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                                        OpenAfterPublish:=True

        'remove helper sheet
        'remove alerts to stop the delete confirmation popping up
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        HelperSheet.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        ActiveSheet.Protect AllowFiltering:=True

    End Sub
```

Comment: @MGae2M please provide screen shot of the `ActiveSheet` you are referring to.  Very hard to assist without the answer if the original data set is not provided.

Comment: @MGae2M the answer I provided will save the page setup print area to pdf. What you can also do Is create a "helper" sheet in your code and then copy the ranges to that sheet and then save that sheet as pdf. But again its hard to figure out with out seeing the sheet and what you want out

Comment: @MGae2M alright. I hope you get some more assistance as I cant seem to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I correct my Question, that has wrong in `ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4:H4" & _
 ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tblInsRep").ListRows.Count + 4).Address` line. Please revise your answer. Thanks.

Comment: The **first episode** of question is: How can send a Range directly (and quiet) to `..ExportAsFixedFormat` procedure?  and **seccond one** is: How can appending such form of a filtered table, when change filtering criteria of a column, at end of one pdf file in new page section. Regard.

Comment: I need append new form of filtered table, at the end of one pdf file. Sheet helper now appropriated, because source table format is needed. (as in columns width & Table styles, Row height and etc.

Comment: @MGae2M You really not helping me to help you, So, my last attempt. See it if works for you, otherwise you will need Acrobat Professional to be able to access the combining function to join the pdfs after exporting.

Comment: With great thanks, unfortunately your answer not suitable, because of loosing formats in `Helpersheet `. Of course I had installed Adobe Acrobat Professional.